# Trying to query my Firestore database to retrieve results where a field = current users userUID

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query my google Firestore database to retrieve data where the `userUID` field = that of the current user. As of know I have hardcoded the `userUID` although this must change to be unique for whatever user is logged in. My code is below:

```
   public void viewMyAttendance(View v) {

    attendanceRef3.whereEqualTo("userUID", "rJe547HwBrWFWa90zVdUl6PYfo03")//("userUID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser())
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            String data = "";

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                Attendance attendance = documentSnapshot.toObject(Attendance.class);
                //attendance.setDocumentID(documentSnapshot.getId());

                //Session session = documentSnapshot.toObject(Session.class);

                String sessionID = attendance.getSessionID();
                String studentID = attendance.getUserUID();
                //String documentID = session.getDocumentID();

                data += "Session ID: " + sessionID + "\n" + "User UID: " + studentID + "\n\n";
            }
            textViewData.setText(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here?

Comment: Currently I have the userUID for one user hardcoded, I want this to change for each user who signs in so that userUID field = the userUID of the current user and not what I have hardcoded in

Comment: It looks like you've commented out the code to use Firebase Auth to get the UID.

Comment: What error are you getting when usign uid ? String uid = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();  @SeanGallagher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently I have the userUID for one user hardcoded, I want this to change for each user who signs in

To solve this, you need to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) so you can get the `uid`from the `FirebaseUser` object like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Comment: Works just fine, sorry have been away on holidays and just updating the answer, thanks